# Change the color of "=[{+" etc. in Atom output

Tags: colors, atom-editor

Say I have an error in Atom. It prints out the message, but my background is dark and a lot of the symbols (e.g., `+`, `{`, `[`, `=`, etc.) are dark blue, making it really difficult to see.

Is it possible to change the dark blue to, say, light blue?

Comment: Are you using any extension for coloring?

Comment: I dont think so - I started using Atom (from Spyder) two days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Click on File > Style Sheet option and add these line at last:

```css
atom-text-editor.editor .syntax--keyword.syntax--operator {
    color:red;
}
```

Change the color as you need. Those symbols are called operators. The `syntax--operator` option can be found in Developer Tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>). With this method, multiple options can also be combined through hierarchy. For example, the following style makes operators in Red and double quoted strings in Blue. Colors can also be in [Hex color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet).

```css
atom-text-editor.editor {
  .syntax--keyword.syntax--operator {
   color:red;
 }
 .syntax--string.syntax--quoted.syntax--double {
     color:blue;
 }
}
```

**Source:** [Atom Discuss: Why logical operators are not colored in one dark syntax theme](https://discuss.atom.io/t/why-logical-operators-are-not-colored-in-one-dark-syntax-theme/22496/)

Comment: Thank you - how do you changer colors of other classes (say strings)? Is there some kind of cheat-sheet?

Comment: @CutePoison As I said you can get those values from Developers Tools. For strings that will be `atom-text-editor.editor .syntax--string.syntax--quoted.syntax--double`.